# Right Tooltip Menu using HTML CSS Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a menu which opens up to the right like a tooltip. I tried various bootstrap methods. I am not able to add HTML li in the tooltip.

[image]

Comment: It will be helpful if you could share the 'various' bootstrap methods so we can exclude them in our solutions.

Comment: @RehbanKhatri I tried adding HTML to the title in bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a little bit of `jquery` for that and enabling the `data-html` attribute equal to `true` if the html is complex i-e `data-html="true"`. Then you can use html inside tooltip like this:

```js
$('.tooltip-demo.well').tooltip({
  selector: "a[rel=tooltip]"
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>


<div class="tooltip-demo well">
  <p style="margin-bottom: 0;" class="muted">Tight pants next level keff chambray. Beard stumptown, cardigans banh mi lomo thundercats. Tofu biodiesel williamsburg marfa, four loko mcsweeney's cleanse vegan chambray. A <a title="<h1><b>OH WOWOWO</b> <em>one</em> here too</h1>" data-html="true" rel="tooltip"
      href="#">really ironic</a> artisan w
  </p>
</div>
```